# Autosave Not Working

Tags: 7, nodes

I wanted to provide a feature to autosave the data while adding the article so that user can restore the content in the event he goes to some other page.

For that I am using [Autosave](http://drupal.org/project/autosave) module. I have installed it and set it for my content type. But it is not showing any kind of message that form has been saved.
Also I have checked that it is not running in "Stealth Mode", so it must give message that it has been saved.

Is there anything I am missing. I am using drupal 7 and latest version of autosave ie 7.x-2.1

Also it would be better if someone could suggest some other module that helps to accomplish this.

-- Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the issue queue for the module and reported this there first? This site isn't for module bug reports

Answer (score 1):

**Autosave** module works fine with a multilingual Drupal site.

So I'm assuming that you are working on a single language Drupal site.

In order to make **Autosave** module work on single language Drupal site, you need to apply this patch [file](http://drupal.org/files/autosave-single_site_language_and_form_restore_problem.patch)

**Edit:**

The patch file should be for Autosave 7.x-2.x-dev

Check the actual [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1936756)

Comment: It is not working. It is giving some error of service unavailable.

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention that the patch is for autosave-7.x-2.x-dev - try to apply it and see if you'll get the same errors

Answer (score 1):

[Save Form State](https://drupal.org/project/form_save_state) can be a good alternative. This module provides a way to autosave data entered in any Drupal form without actually submitting the form, which helps if the user is writing an article or a comment and the browser crashed or the power went down, or even if the window was closed accidently.